# How use custom alias field from select fields in join?

Tags: mysql, sql

How use custom alias field from select fields in join?

```
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(`ufn`.`value`, '.', `uln`.`value`, CAST(RAND()*1e6 AS UNSIGNED))) AS `newlogin`
FROM `user_firstname` AS `ufn`
INNER JOIN `user_lastname` AS `uln`
LEFT JOIN `user` AS `u` ON `u`.`login` = `newlogin`
WHERE `ufn`.`sex` = 'male' AND `u`.`id` IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Result: [sql-error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Latt8.png)

EDIT:

My solution, but, ...:

```
SELECT @newlogin
FROM (
    SELECT @newlogin := LOWER(CONCAT(`ufn`.`value`, '.', `uln`.`value`, CAST(RAND()*1e6 AS UNSIGNED)))
    FROM `user_firstname` AS `ufn`
    INNER JOIN `user_lastname` AS `uln`
    WHERE `ufn`.`sex` = 'male'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
) AS `ufnX`
LEFT JOIN `user` AS `u` ON `u`.`login` = @newlogin
WHERE `u`.`id` IS NULL
```

Comment: Scope issue. Wrap the first join up in a derived table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the new login in a subquery and join it in:

```
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(`ufn`.`value`, '.', `uln`.`value`, nl.num)) AS newlogin
FROM (SELECT CAST(RAND()*1e6 AS UNSIGNED))) AS num
     ) nl CROSS JOIN
     `user_firstname` ufn CROSS JOIN
     `user_lastname` uln LEFT JOIN
     `user` u
     ON `u`.`login` = LOWER(CONCAT(ufn.`value`, '.', uln.`value`, nl.num))
WHERE `ufn`.`sex` = 'male' AND `u`.`id` IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Note I replaced the `INNER JOIN` with `CROSS JOIN`.  `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` makes no sense.

EDIT:

You seem to want to test multiple values to get a match.  You could try putting the comparison in the `HAVING` clause.  That clause can reference columns in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(ufn.`value`, '.', uln.`value`, CAST(RAND()*1e6 AS UNSIGNED))) AS newlogin
FROM user_firstname` ufn CROSS JOIN
     `user_lastname` uln 
WHERE `ufn`.`sex` = 'male'
HAVING NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM user u
                   WHERE u.login = newlogin
                  )
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```